# How to print twig variable inside other variable?

Tags: html, twig

Here what I want to do,

**In twig**

```
<div class="content">
    {{ page.desc|raw }}
</div>

{% set name = "Home" %}
```

In editor, for above {{ page.desc|raw }}:

```
This is the {{ name }} page and this content is for {{ name }} page.
```

What I want to do is print **Home** where **{{ name }}** is added.

I don't have much knowledge on Twig and I don't know whether it's available in twig or not.

Could you please help?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: the page desc contains a twig template?

Comment: Yes, in a twig template.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html), this should solve your problem :)